# Is there a way to open instagram app on 'add page' from my expo app (react native solution)?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, instagram, expo

I am new to react-native/expo, so maybe because of it, I can't find any solution.

I want to open 'Instagram app' from my new app. But the Instagram should be opened on 'add' page, where the user can choose an image and upload it.
I saw examples on Instagram page examples where they are trying to do so with 'java' code, but **I want to find a solution on js (expo\react-native functionality)**.

I found this on instagram https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/
It is made on java and I can't understand how can I translate it to react-native/js

**Try #1**

I can open instagram by

```
 Linking.openURL(`http://instagram.com/_u/travelerandrii`)
```

but, it will open the app on some page (you can set any username instead of travelerandrii)

**Try #2**

I saw few examples with something like

```
 Linking.openURL(`instagram://library?AssetPath=${encodedURL}`)
```

But in this case on my phone, I'd get an exception and it'll say 'Error: No Activity found to handle Intent'

It seems to me that I don't do the call right for instagram app or I don't have some 'permissions'

If someone knows how to open instagram app on 'add' page, please help me :)

Comment: Did you find any solution?